# Storing retrieving data:image in Firebase very slow

Tags: firebase

I just tried storing `data:image` in Firebase.

The tested image file size less than 500kb and just 1 image.

The storing and retrieving image is OK but when updating the other value with `text` become very slow.

It is almost delay 2 mins per letter change.

Any idea?

**It is fine if I use http://www.google.com/image.png directly.

**Updated**

I create a plunker with description please check it out
http://plnkr.co/edit/lRy5vCbu0RXR2pEPKC7y?p=preview

Comment: How are you storing the data and how are you trying to update the text? (Show us some code). About the image, I get a 404 Error :)

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the desired language / API.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I updated the question.   and the language api is firebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving every image in the database each time a letter is changed. This is because you have synced your angularFire instance to the entire images hierarchy. Since angularFire uses on('value'), then it is downloading the entire list of images on each change.

You can avoid this by using angularFireCollection, which relies on child_added/updated/removed, so that it's syncing each child as it changes instead of all images any time any child changes.

An even better solution would be to split out your image data to a separate path and put some sort of update counter in images/, so that you can fetch a new image any time it changes. Do these even need to be synced in real time? Are images being "edited" frequently?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, angularFire) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.images = angularFireCollection('https://datauri.firebaseio-demo.com/images/');

});
```

Check out [this article on denormalization](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) for some background.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The images list with each image with text. And both image and text need to be synced in real time BUT image is not edited frequently. 

So what is the recommended way to deal with this?   denormalize like what you said?

Comment: Confusing something. If i'm using `angularFire()` with `images/` node. Each letter I change will affect every single child node under `images/`?

Comment: OMG, I got what you meant. Why it re-retrieving every time I changing the other field? This should not be happened. 
Is this behaviour of firebase or just angularFire?
 If it is firebase, I have refresh my mind to redesign the nodes.

Comment: Well, your data is in a tree. And you are basically monitoring the trunk with angularFire (which calls on('value', ...)). So any time a leaf changes, the entire tree is returned to the on('value') call. As you now suspect, [data structure is very important in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html).

Comment: I saw a note in angularFire, `// TODO: Optimize to use child events instead of whole "value".`   Is that mean it will not retrieving the entire tree if angularFire author change it to support `child events`?

Comment: True. In the mean time, just use angularFireCollection for this instance, which already uses child events.